# jQuery.ajax only works once

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome-extension

A part of my chrome extension tests to see if the user is connected to the internet. It works once perfectly but after it runs, $.ajax === undefined and I don't know why. I don't see any setters which could modify $.ajax

```
var testInternet = function(callback) {
    "use strict";
    var testURLs, doCallback, i, failCount;
    if (! callback) {
        callback = function(){};
    }
    doCallback = true;
    failCount = 0;
    testURLs = [
    "http://clients5.google.com/pagead/drt/dn/dn.js"
    ];
    for (i= 0; i < testURLs.length; i++) {
        testConnection(testURLs[i], function(success){
            if (success && doCallback) {
                doCallback = false;
                callback(true);
                return;
            } else {
                failCount += 1;
                if (failCount === testURLs.length) {
                    callback(false);
                    return;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

var testConnection = function(url, callback) {
    "use strict";
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        timeout: 10000,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            callback(true);
            return;
        },
        error: function(data) {,
            callback(false);
            return;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: There must be something else going on. This code doesn't seem to be the issue.

Comment: How is jQuery getting loaded if there's no network connection?

Comment: @jfriend00 It could be cached.

Comment: I am literally pasting this code into the console, I do testInternet(function(cb){console.log(cb);}) It returns true the first time, the second time it fails. After some testing, i found that $.ajax === undefined after the function is called but not before.

Comment: @jfriend00 It's a chrome extension not a webpage. It ships with jQuery.

Comment: @jfriend00 It's not externally loaded

Comment: I wonder if the context in your console is not necessarily the context of your extension the second time.  Presumably your extension has its own namespace, right?  Are you sure you are operating in that namespace that second time?

Comment: @JamesFargotson So if you avoid calling this function then check in the console if `$.ajax` is defined, it is defined? Then you call the function and do the same check again and it's not? That's what is happening?

Comment: @plalx That is exactly what's happening.

Comment: @JamesFargotson What tools are you using to develop the extension and run code within the extension's context? Can you put break points?

Comment: I get the same error if I just do $.ajax. I can only use this once. $.ajax({
 url: "http://clients5.google.com/pagead/drt/dn/dn.js",
 timeout: 10000,
 cache: false,
 success: function(data) {
  console.log(true);
  return;
 },
 error: function(data) {
  console.log(false);
  return;
 }
});

Comment: It seems it happens when my url is "clients5.google.com/pagead/drt/dn/dn.js" but not when it's just "google.com"

Comment: @plalx The only tools I'm using is textmate but that's not how I'm running this code. I'm just pasting it into the console. I get the same result regardless of if I paste it into the popup console or the background console.

Comment: @JamesFargotson That was one of my ideas. Perhaps the script gets interpreted by jQuery? Try adding `dataType: 'text'` to the ajax options.

Comment: @plalx That worked! Thank you. Add it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like because you are getting a .js file, jQuery automatically defaults the `dataType` to `script`, which will cause jQuery to evaluate the script being loaded. Specifying `dataType: 'text'` should prevent that unwanted behavior.